# convert a char[] to jcharArray and then create a string in JAVA with raw bytes

Tags: java, android, c++, string, java-native-interface

I am new to JNI and have a requirement to convert a `char[]` to `jcharArray` and then create a `String` in JAVA. This `String` will be passed in a `Parcel` to other layers. When reading from the `Parcel` I want the other component to get the same byte sequence as of char array.

```
jchar *jcharBuffer1 = (jchar *)calloc(sizeof(jchar), length+1);

for (count = 0; count<length; count ++) {
    jcharBuffer1[count] = (jchar)c_array[count];
}
jcharArray  str1 = env->NewCharArray(length+1);
env->SetCharArrayRegion (str1, 0, length+1, jcharBuffer1);
```

This is my java code

```
public void testing(char[] array){
         String test_str = new String(array);
         Setdata(test_str)
}

public void Setdata(String data) {
    Parcel request = Parcel.obtain();
    Parcel resp = Parcel.obtain();
    try {
        .
        .
        request.writeString(data);
    }
}
```

In the whole process I want the same byte sequence to arrive even after converting in to string. These bytes are decoded output from Base64 string from a server.
1. The `jchar` is 16bits but C-byte is 8 bit. So how can I achieve this requirement?

Comment: Unless you only have pure ASCII (i.e. 7-bits) you need to take care of the encoding. I would simplify the problem by returning the C char[] as a byte[] into the java code, then create the String there.

Comment: If I create a string in Java, how to mention the encoding format? will it again try to convert this in to a UTF8 encoded string?

Comment: String s = new String(byteArray, "UTF-8") if the encoding is UTF-8 and back to byte[] array = s.getBytes("UTF-8"). This is a FAQ.

Comment: But the byte values are changed if I try to print with string.getBytes() in java. What I need is to form a java string without changing byte value. Any help?

Comment: Search your C library for a function that takes your C char array and creates a unicode encoded wchar_t array from it. Once you have that it can be used as jchar data.